# T-SQL UPDATE statement to efficiently extend a DateTime2 value a number of days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I need to iterate a table and extend an Expiration Date for all rows.  The column name is ExpirationUtc (DateTime2) and I want to add 90 days to every row.  What is the most efficient SQL query to run, i.e. an UPDATE statement that will take the current ExpirationUtc and replace it with ExpirationUtc + 90 days?

Thank you.

Comment: One thing to remember, when using SQL, is don't think `iterate over rows`, think, `I need to update a batch of rows, based on a criteria`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update your_table
set ExpirationUtc = dateadd(day, 90, ExpirationUtc)
```